# Ms access 2010 how to open MSpaint with a blank page using the form name as a file name?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I made a program to create Jobs field Tickets, and i want to add a option in the same form that open MSPaint or other program in a blank page using the ticket number as a file name, so, whoever is creating the Ticket can hand draw anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an empty template image file with appropriate dimensions and file type at a constant path
- use `FileCopy` to copy it to your desired path & file name
- use `Shell` to launch a `mspaint.exe` command-line with your file name as parameter.

Comment: Can you give me an example? how i create an empty template and copy the file?

Comment: Ok i Got it now, Thanks.